# Docker container functions don't operate on Mac/Win10 local

Tags: docker

I launch web application with docker, docker-compose.

On remote linux, all function launch without problems.

But on Mac local and Win10 local, some issues occur.

Mac issue is container and api can't load file with FileNotFoundException.
Func need to load file and scan, parse data.
But file didn't loaded, API Func return Null data.
File share with docker volume.

And Win10 issue is on build time.
On Mac and Linux, build has no problems.
But, Win10 can't load docker init.sh.

```
board    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/00-init.sh
board    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: 31: /docker-entrypoint.d/00-init.sh: not found
board exited with code 127
```

I think these issues occured by path and fs problem.
But I don't know exact reason and solution.

How can I fix these?

Comment: Which daemon and runtime environment do you use. On Windows 10: Docker-Desktop? Linux-Subsystem?

Comment: Yes! Remote linux use docker-ce. Windows use WSL-Docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem on Windows 10.

The reason is encoding-difference between Windows and Mac/Linux.

In sh file, CR is 0d and LF is 0a.
And if CR(0d) contains, container can't read this file.

So, remove all CR(0d) in file.

Comment: Hou might want to add .gitattributes containing "*.sh  text eol=lf" to avoid this in the future.